# How to assign to organizations in initialState actual array of objects instead of promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I want to assign to *organizations* in initialState an array of objects, but instead I assign Promise. I know what is the reason, of course because the **getOrganizaitons** is Promise, how can I assign actual objects?

```
const getOrganizaitons = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(`${SERVER_URL}/api/v1/org`,
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { Authorization: TOKEN_NAZIM }
    });
  console.log(res.data.results);
  return res.data.results;
};

//getOrganizaitons();

export const initialState = {
  authenticated: null,
  organizations: getOrganizaitons()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign something *synchronously* if it's retrieved *asynchronously*. In this situation, export a Promise that resolves to the `organizations`, then wait for the Promise to resolve inside the component:

```
export const organizationsProm =  axios.get(`${SERVER_URL}/api/v1/org`,
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { Authorization: TOKEN_NAZIM }
    })
  .then(({ data }) => data.results);
```

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(null);
  const [organizations, setOrganizations] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    organizationsProm.then(setOrganizations).catch(handleErrors);
  }, []);
  // ...
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I can't use useEffect since it is regular js file.

Comment: It's just an example to show how you can wait for the Promise to resolve - however you're using the export, you need to change it so that it can work with a Promise instead of the data up front. If you're using a class component, you can use `componentDidMount` instead.

Comment: @NZMAI You need to `useEffect` in each component where you want to use the `initialState`. (Although you should get a better name for that - the initial state would be empty, then you fill it with the loaded organisations)